# Rails - UndefinedMethod in model#new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

My routes.rb looks as such:

```
resources :users do
 resources :reservations do
  resources :orders
 end
end

resources :reservations do
 resources :orders 
end
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :orders, :through => :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
  belongs_to :user
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

Controllers:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
   if current_user
    @user         = User.find_by_id(current_user)
    @reservation  = @user.reservations.build
   else
    @reservation  = Reservation.new
   end
  end

  #leaving out the save portion to make question shorter. 
  def create
   if current_user
    @user         = User.find(current_user)
    @reservation  = @user.reservations.create(reservation_params)
   else
    @reservation  = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
   end
  end 
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
   if current_user
    @user         = User.find_by_id(current_user)
    @order        = @user.build_order
   else
    @reservation  = Reservation.find_by_id(params[:reservation_id])
    @order        = @reservation.build_order
   end
  end

  def create
   if current_user
    @user         = User.where(current_user)
    @order        = @user.orders.create(order_params)
   else
    @reservation  = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @order        = @reservation.create_order(order_params)
   end
  end
end
```

**Error**

NoMethodError in OrdersController#new

undefined method `build_order' for #

Full stack trace is as such:

```
activemodel (4.2.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in                     `method_missing'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:29:in `new'
actionpack (4.2.5)     lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `    process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in     `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in     `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5)     lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in     `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in     `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in     `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5)             lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5)     lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5)     lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:561:in `handle_request'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `call'
puma (3.1.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I'm able to make a reservation and order when there is no 'current_user' but where I'm running into an issue is when a user is signed-in I'm able to make a reservation and it saves to the DB but then I get a no method error in the Orders#new controller @order = @user.build_order line. I have tried a lot of variations such as @user.order.new, @user.order.build

I've also tried @order = @user.reservations.order(params[:reservation_id]) but this leads me to a 'to_key' issue for the orders _form.

None of the options I've mentioned work nor more options that I have tried which I don't remember anymore. I would greatly appreciate help.

Please let me know if more information is needed from me, I will try to post it soon as possible.

Comment: Post the full error message with line number.

Comment: @Substantial just added the error messages but can't seem to add line numbers to the actual error messages.

Comment: I see them. You did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `@user.build_order` to `@user.orders.build`.

The former is used for `belongs_to` associations which point to an owning object.

[image: belongs_to methods]

The latter is for `has_many`-style associations which point to a collection, ie. "build onto this user's orders."

[image: has_many methods]

Your users have a collection of orders (`has_many` association), so you call `build` on the user's collection of orders instead on the user itself.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, i really appreciate it, you helped a lot. Along with @Dharam. I'm not sure who to vote for correct answer, technically he answer a minute before you and I'd hate to rob him of the correct answer. But since you have a much more in-depth answer I think it would make sense to give you the correct answer.

Comment: So, after taking your advice and seeing what I was doing wrong I went through some of the documentation to see where I could be going wrong with the Order#create action. I'm not sure if my associations are wrong? Error im getting is:
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection in OrdersController#create
Cannot modify association 'User#orders' because the source reflection class 'Order' is associated to 'Reservation' via :has_one. 
I would really appreciate it if you could help. Didn't make a new question since i felt it's very related to this question.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by changing up the associations. rather than '@user.orders.create' I just changed it to '@reservation.create_order' and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `User` `has_many :orders`. `@user.build_order` works only if you have `has_one :order` or `belongs_to :order` in your `User`.

As the `User` `has_many :orders`, you should use `@user.orders.build` in your `OrdersController#new`.

Refer to [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more info on how to build relations.